# dynamically set name within function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two functions;

```
function grabScreenshot(streamKey, date, time){
     screenshotInterval = setInterval(function() { 
     
        //not important
    
        });
    
    }, 60000);
    }

function updateTimeout(streamKey, date, time){
 timeoutInterval = setInterval(function() { 

        //not important

    });
}, 5000);
}
```

The problem I am currently facing; I need the name `screenshotInterval` and `timeoutInterval` to be dynamically set based on the information provided as `time` in the function call;

Lets say I called this `grabScreenshot(1, 2, 1620534515);`

How would i get the `screenshotInterval` to be instead called `screenshotInterval-1620534515`

The reason I need to be able to dynamically set this name is so that later on I can

`clearInterval(screenshotInterval-1620534515());`

And alot of these intervals will be running simultaneously.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). If you describe your full goal and context, there is probably a clearer way to do whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
let arr = {};

function grabScreenshot(streamKey, date, time) {
  arr[`screenshotInterval-${time}`] = setInterval(function() {

    console.log("hi");



  }, 600);
}

let time = 1566777
grabScreenshot(null, "date", time)

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("called")
  clearInterval(arr[`screenshotInterval-${time}`]);

}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set dynamic variables in document:

```
  var intervals=[]
  function grabScreenshot(streamKey, date, time){
     let vari = "screenshotInterval_"+time;
     intervals.push(vari); // stored here so we can clear it later
     document[vari] = setInterval(function() { 
        console.log(vari, document[vari])
      }, 1000);

    }

    function cancel(index) {
        clearInterval(document[intervals[index]]);
    }
```

Comment: It would likely be better to create a class around Job Management that holds the state for these setIntervals with a method to cancel and start. That way you can have multiple types and prevent the state from polluting global document.